# Javascript event firing before action occurs

Tags: javascript, object, audio, dom-events

I am trying to write a script so that when I play an embedded sound object, a picture that I also have embedded will change.

```
function changePic() {
document.getElementById("sound").onclick = transform(document.getElementById("pic"));
}
    
function transform (pic) {
pic.src = "";
alert ("done");
}
```

The problem is that when I load the page, the Javascript code automatically runs even though I don't click play (`autostart` is set to false) on the sound object. Does anyone have an idea as to what is causing this?

Comment: When are you executing `changePic()`, also you should attach events like this: `element.addEventListener` and `element.attachEvent` in IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `onclick = transform(...)`, you're *calling* `transform` and assigning the result to `onclick`.

You need to set the handler to an anonymous function that calls `transform`, like this:

```
document.getElementById("sound").onclick = function() {
    transform(document.getElementById("pic"));
};
```

However, this is the wrong way to add events.
You should call `element.addEventListener` / `element.attachEvent`.  (or just use jQuery)